# How to configure the pool size of a DBappender in logBack with HikariDataSource ?

Tags: datasource, logback, hikaricp

This is my logback configuration with HikariDatasource :

```
<appender name="AUDIT-DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DataSourceConnectionSource">
        <dataSource class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
            <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
            <jdbcUrl>jdbc:mysql://myurl:3306/audit?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;useSSL=false</jdbcUrl>
            <username>mysqlciuser</username>
            <password>mysqlcipwd</password>
        </dataSource>
    </connectionSource>
</appender>
```

In the documentation of logback https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html, I don't find a way to limit the default pool size(10) created by the datasource. 
I try to use the tag :  `<maxPoolSize>5</maxPoolSize>` but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should you use the following config line:

```
<maximumPoolSize>50</maximumPoolSize>
```

The issue is that setter and field name are contradicting in HikariConfig:

```
 @Override
   public void setMaximumPoolSize(int maxPoolSize)
   {
      if (maxPoolSize < 1) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxPoolSize cannot be less than 1");
      }
      this.maxPoolSize = maxPoolSize;
   }
```